# NSJSONSerialization with an integer

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

I'm writing an iOS application that gets data from a web request.  The request returns the following:
`{"hash":"0369a5d5e65335309b2b1502dc96b5aba691b9451c83b9","error":0}`

I get the data from the `NSData* responseData` object as follows:

```
NSDictionary* JSONdata = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_responseData options:0 error:&error];

NSInteger responseError = (NSInteger)[JSONdata objectForKey:@"error"];
```

However, `responseError` is coming back uninitialized (filled with garbage values).  I tried changing `NSInteger` to `NSString*` but that yields the following error

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9d02220'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: please read up on primates vs classes

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an NSNumber. Primitive values will not work for as iOS parses the data in NSObjects: NSArray, NSDictionary, NSNumber, NSString, and NSNull.

Try this: `NSNumber *responseError = [JSONdata objectForKey:@"error"];`

Then to convert to an NSInteger you can do this:
`NSInteger responseInt = [responseError integerValue];`                                     this will return an integer value.

Also for future reference, an NSDictionary cannot contain any primitive values.